# Eye blink detection - how to?

Tags: android

I want to detect eye blink and after eye blink I want to capture frame and save it as bitmap.

I used the Firebase Ml kit sample [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) for face recolonization to detect the eye blink and its working but it is pausing the video frames as it is processing the frame to detect the face in between.

I want a solution that can detect eye blink with good quality video and then want to capture frame.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you have cracked the code, and everything is working fine. You are also able to get the desired result. The only problem at hand is to do this entire task efficiently using main/ background thread concepts so that your code doesn't freeze the app UI.

As you have not given any code references of your app, I will assume you have used Kotlin as the programming language for your app. Kotlin provides an excellent and easy way to perform background tasks, using [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html).

Steps to use coroutines in your app (using anko):

- Include this library in app-level `build.gralde`:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) for the latest version of this library.

- Wherever you want to perform a background resource-heavy task, do as follows:

```
doAsync {
    // do background task such as computations here
    uiThread {
        // after the background task is completed, and you have some results, interact with the UI here to show the results to the user.
    }
}
```

Please give this solution a sincere try, and I'm sure your issue will be resolved. I had made a similar app module months ago where I needed to process frames from a camera feed in realtime and show results. This is the solution that I ended up using. It's fast, efficient, and precise.

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't break the code at that level to process the frames in different thread because we need to handle the camera as well. Apart from that, In that case I will have to buffer the frames in some data structure and that may cause Out Of Memory Exception.

Comment: Coroutine are light-weight threads. A light weight thread means it doesn’t map on native thread, so it doesn’t require context switching on processor, so they are faster. You can use multiple coroutines this way. Example:

```kotlin
doAsync {
    uiThread {
        doAsync {    
            uiThread {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Example code: https://gist.github.com/mumayank/03e9dfd18809f8e0f69344b30d0b1ffe

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say is (1) you won't need to do this in different threads as you are going to use coroutines, and (2) why do you feel that buffering of the frames would be required? Is Firebase ML taking too much time to give back results when supplied a frame from the camera feed?

Comment: Not sure if it will work like that ,because their supporting classes are in java and they are all designed to work collectively.Please take a look at the sample project https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit for complete understanding